How to tag a logical break (dinkus)?
In typography a logical break is often denoted with a dinkus, usually a centered row of three asterisks.  How do we tag this to make it accessible for screen readers?

Interesting. In the web context one would use probably make use of the ARIA separator role: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/separator_role

A dinkus  is the no tile of an subsection, so what mean exactly "make it accessible"? Show an outline of no titles? You can use \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{***}  and \phantomsection  to include each  dinku in the outline, but that have little sense if there are more than one, except if you name each dinku differently (*** A, *** B, or so ...). bt then, have  sense specify the logical parts  in the ToC but hide which part is in the text?.

@fran: i basically want to make a pause in the reading

With pause do you mean disable vertical continuous scrolling in some ebook reader or so?  AFAIK the only minimally related with that on LaTeX source side are the Beamer presentations, were you can  and control the time each part is displayed with  \transduration, \pause, or overlays commands to simulate incremental displays and even a pseudo scrolling effect, but there not any scroll features,  simply the content  of the frames is partially repeated in several pages, that I guess that is not what you are looking for.

@Fran it is for a screen reader, so the document is converted into speech audio which is read aloud by the application. A pause therefore is maybe 1-2 seconds of silence in the audio output when such a *** line is encountered.

Then the solution will be use punctuation marks or insert special pause tags or symbols that depend on the TTS system you're using. The help that LaTeX help could add I  guess will be only make that tags white,  to hide these controls to the human eye, but not to the TTS tool. If the speech is automatic when each pdf page is charged in the viewer, then presentations could be a solution using   dinkus at the very end of the slide and \transdurations equal to the seconds need for speech the whole page plus the x seconds of pause.
